# Map of item movements between two lists

Tags: python, algorithm

How can I decompose a reordering of values into a set of `ix -> new_ix` movements?

For example

```
initial values: abcd
final values: badc
value movements: 0->1, 2->3
```

```
initial values: abcd
final values: bcda
value movements: 0->3
```

In other words - given two lists A and B, find a set of pairs `(x, y)` such that applying the action `move value in list A at index x to index y` for every pair will result in list B.

Here's what I came up with but it fails on the 2nd test case:

```py
def get_movements(initial_values, final_values):
    movements = set()
    for ix, val_name in enumerate(final_values):
        ix_new = initial_values.index(val_name)
        movements.add(tuple(sorted([ix, ix_new])))
    return movements


def apply_movements(values, movements):
    from copy import copy
    values = copy(values)
    for m in movements:
        values.insert(m[0], values.pop(m[1]))
    return values


# Test 1
initial_values = list('abcd')
final_values = list('badc')
movements = get_movements(initial_values, final_values)
assert (apply_movements(initial_values, movements) == final_values)

# Test 2
initial_values = list('abcd')
final_values = list('bcda')
movements = get_movements(initial_values, final_values)
assert (apply_movements(initial_values, movements) == final_values)
```

Comment: What's your definition of movement? In your first example, all four elements changed positions; why do you only say `a` and `c` moved?

Comment: Same with the second example, though it's easier to make an argument that `b`, `c`, and `d` did not move relative to each other, and that the *minimum* number of movements necessary is to shift `a` from the beginning to the end.

Comment: @chepner I think the best definition of my desired algorithm would be "given two lists A and B, find a set of values pairs `(x, y)` such that applying the action `move value at location x to y` for every pair to list A will result in list B.", which is what `apply_movements` tests for in my code. An ideal solution would find the lowest number of pairs possible.

Comment: I think that the first one is a bit off, no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry I mixed the letters up accidentally, I think the current edit should be correct.

Comment: Given list A `abcd`, if you take the value at 0 (a) and move it to 1, and take the value at 2 (c) and move it to 3, you get list B `bacd` so a set of valid pairs for my definition above would be `{(0, 1), (2, 3)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not efficient, but you could go through the elements of the final result and fill them in one at a time. That guarantees that the elements you shift with a pop are still unprocessed. So if you want to do

```
abcd -> dcba
```

you first look at `d`, then `c`, then `b` and finally `a`. That way, when you pop `c`, it won't dislocate `d`, etc:

```
a = list('abcd')
b = 'dcba'

assert set(a) == set(b)

steps = []
for dest, letter in enumerate(b):
    src = a.index(letter)
    if src == dest:
        continue
    steps.append((src, dest))
    a.insert(dest, a.pop(src))
```

This will not always lead to the shortest or prettiest solution, but it will always work. A slightly more efficient version, but with the same overall complexity would be to avoid re-inserting elements:

```
steps = []
for dest, letter in enumerate(b):
    src = a.index(letter)
    if src != 0:
        steps.append((src + dest, dest))
    a.pop(src)
```